# TextView and Button updates only once

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments, bluetooth

I have issue and I can't get it done. I have MainActivity that has Slide Menu with fragments. After starting app HomeFragment is set in the window. In Home Fragment I have handler which is getting messages from bluetooth service. This handler changes text view in Home Fragment from "you're not connected" -> "connecting..." -> "you're connected". It works perfectly after starting app. But when I choose another fragment from slide menu and return to the Home Fragment, the text view is not showing up. In LogCat everything looks fine - TextView.getText() returns proper text. But it is not shown - TextView field is empty. Below I  show you MainActivity and HomeFragment class + HomeFragment xml. I tried runOnUiThread, handler.post, nothing is working...

## MainActivity.java

```
    package io.panwrona.cheaproomduino;
    public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity{


    private static final String CLASS_TAG = "MainActivity";

    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView mDrawerList;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
    private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;

    // used to store app title
    private CharSequence mTitle;

    // slide menu items
    private String[] navMenuTitles;
    private TypedArray navMenuIcons;

    private ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> navDrawerItems;
    private NavDrawerListAdapter adapter;

    private List<String> sceneryTypeList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
//        initFragment(new HomeFragment());
//
//        if(savedInstanceState == null){
//
//        }



        mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();

        // load slide menu items
        navMenuTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_drawer_items);

        // nav drawer icons from resources
        navMenuIcons = getResources()
                .obtainTypedArray(R.array.nav_drawer_icons);

        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_slidermenu);

        navDrawerItems = new ArrayList<NavDrawerItem>();

        // adding nav drawer items to array
        // Home
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[0], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(0, -1)));
        // Find People
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[1], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(1, -1)));
        // Photos
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[2], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(2, -1)));
        // Communities, Will add a counter here
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[3], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(3, -1)));
        // Pages
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[4], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(4, -1)));
        // What's hot, We  will add a counter here
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[5], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(5, -1)));

        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[6], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(6,-1)));


        // Recycle the typed array
        navMenuIcons.recycle();

        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new SlideMenuClickListener());

        // setting the nav drawer list adapter
        adapter = new NavDrawerListAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
                navDrawerItems);
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);

        // enabling action bar app icon and behaving it as toggle button

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
                R.drawable.ic_drawer, //nav menu toggle icon
                R.string.app_name, // nav drawer open - description for accessibility
                R.string.app_name // nav drawer close - description for accessibility
        ) {
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to show action bar icons
                supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
                // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to hide action bar icons
                supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
        };
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            // on first time display view for first nav item
            displayView(0);
        }

    }




    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    private class SlideMenuClickListener implements
            ListView.OnItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                                long id) {
            // display view for selected nav drawer item
            displayView(position);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRestart(){
        super.onRestart();
        Log.d(CLASS_TAG, CLASS_TAG + " Restarted");


    }

    @Override
    public void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        Log.d(CLASS_TAG, CLASS_TAG + " Resumed");
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
        // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to show action bar icons
        supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();

    }



    /* *
     * Called when invalidateOptionsMenu() is triggered
     */


    /**
     * Diplaying fragment view for selected nav drawer list item
     * */
    private void displayView(int position) {
        // update the main content by replacing fragments
        Fragment fragment = null;
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                fragment = new HomeFragment();
                break;
            case 1:
                fragment = new DevicesFragment();
                break;
            case 2:
//                i = new Intent(this, SceneryActivity.class);
//                startActivity(i);
                break;
            case 3:
//                i = new Intent(this, SceneryActivity.class);
//                startActivity(i);
                break;
            case 4:
//                i = new Intent(this, SceneryActivity.class);
//                startActivity(i);
                break;
            case 5:
//                i = new Intent(this, SceneryActivity.class);
//                startActivity(i);
                break;
            case 6:
//                i = new Intent(this, SceneryActivity.class);
//                startActivity(i);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }


        if (fragment != null) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();

            // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
            mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
            mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
            setTitle(navMenuTitles[position]);
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
        } else {
            // error in creating fragment

            Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
        mTitle = title;
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
    }

    /**
     * When using the ActionBarDrawerToggle, you must call it during
     * onPostCreate() and onConfigurationChanged()...
     */

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggls
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // if nav drawer is opened, hide the action items
        boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
       // menu.findItem(R.id.bluetooh_options_devices).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy(){
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.d(CLASS_TAG, CLASS_TAG + " Destroyed!");
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause(){
        super.onPause();
        Log.d(CLASS_TAG, CLASS_TAG + " Paused!");
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop(){
        super.onStop();
        Log.d(CLASS_TAG, CLASS_TAG + " Stopped!");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // toggle nav drawer on selecting action bar app icon/title
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }
        // Handle action bar actions click
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.string.action_settings:
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }





    }
```

## HomeFragment.java

```
package io.panwrona.cheaproomduino;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.List;

import io.panwrona.cheaproomduino.connection.BluetoothConnectionService;
import io.panwrona.cheaproomduino.connection.DevicesList;
import io.panwrona.cheaproomduino.database.DatabaseHelper;
import io.panwrona.cheaproomduino.database.TinyDB;
import io.panwrona.cheaproomduino.database.database_models.BluetoothDeviceModel;


public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

    private static final String CLASS_TAG = "HomeFragment";

    // Handlers 'cases'
    public static final int MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGE = 1;
    public static final int MESSAGE_READ = 2;
    public static final int MESSAGE_WRITE = 3;
    public static final int MESSAGE_DEVICE_NAME = 4;
    public static final int MESSAGE_TOAST = 5;


    // Key names received from the BluetoothChatService Handler
    public static final String DEVICE_NAME = "device_name";
    public static final String TOAST = "toast";
    //
//    // Intent request codes
    private static final int REQUEST_CONNECT_DEVICE = 1;
    private static final int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 2;

    private String connectedDeviceName = null;
    private String connectedDeviceAddress = null;

    Context context;
    private Button connectButton;
    private TextView connectTxt;


    BluetoothAdapter btAdapter;
    public BluetoothConnectionService btService = null;
    BluetoothDevice btDevice = null;
    DatabaseHelper db;
    TinyDB tinyDB;





//    public HomeFragment(){}

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        Log.d(CLASS_TAG + "/" + "onCreateView", "in onCreateView");
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

        if(connectButton == null){
        connectButton = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.main_connect_button);
        connectButton.setOnClickListener(new ConnectionClickListener());
        }
        if(connectTxt == null){
        connectTxt = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.try_txt);
        }
        if(tinyDB != null){
            mHandler.sendEmptyMessage(tinyDB.getInt("connection_state"));
        }

        if(btService != null && btService.getCurrentState() == 2){
            connectTxt.setText(tinyDB.getString("connected_device"));
            connectButton.setText(tinyDB.getString("connected_device_btn"));
        }


        return rootView;
    }
private int msgWhat;
    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        if(context == null){
            context = getActivity().getApplicationContext();
        }
        btAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        db = new DatabaseHelper(context);
        tinyDB = new TinyDB(context);



        if(((cBaseApplication)context).getBtService() == null){
            btService = ((cBaseApplication)context).getBtService(mHandler);
        }else{
            btService = ((cBaseApplication)context).getBtService();
        }
        checkBluetoothState();
        try{
            Log.d("HomeFragment", "State: " + btService.getCurrentState());
            String test = "Test";
            byte[] testByte = test.getBytes();
            btService.write(testByte);
        } catch(NullPointerException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        btService.getState();
        if(true){
            connectTxt.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity a){
        super.onAttach(a);
        Log.d(CLASS_TAG, "in onAttach() !");
        if(a == null){
            Log.d(CLASS_TAG, "in onAttach() ! Activity: null");
        } else {
            Log.d(CLASS_TAG, "in onAttach() ! Activity: " + a);

        }
    }

        private final Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                switch (msg.what) {

                    case MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGE:
                        if(true) Log.i(CLASS_TAG, "MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGE: " + msg.arg1);
                        switch (msg.arg1) {
                            case BluetoothConnectionService.STATE_CONNECTED:

                                List<BluetoothDeviceModel> btModels = db.getBluetoothDevicesList();
                                boolean btModelExist = false;
                                for(BluetoothDeviceModel model : btModels){
                                    if(model.getBluetoothDeviceName().equals(connectedDeviceName)){
                                        btModelExist = true;
                                    }else{
                                        btModelExist = false;
                                    }
                                }
                                if(btModelExist != false){

                                    BluetoothDeviceModel model = 
                                            new BluetoothDeviceModel(connectedDeviceName, 
                                            connectedDeviceAddress);

                                    Log.d(CLASS_TAG + "BLUETOOTHDEVICEMODEL", "Bt Device Model: " 
                                            + connectedDeviceName + " " + connectedDeviceAddress);

                                    new AlertBox("Saving bluetooth device...", 
                                            "Do you want to save this device: " 
                                            + connectedDeviceName + " ?",
                                            model, 
                                            getActivity());
                                }
                                tinyDB.putString("connected_device","Connected to: " 
                                        + connectedDeviceName);
                                tinyDB.putString("connected_device_btn", 
                                        "Disconnect");

                                //Log.d(CLASS_TAG + "/" + "Handler", "In State Connected runnable");

                                connectTxt.setText("Connected to: " + connectedDeviceName);
                                connectButton.setText("Disconnect");

                                tinyDB.putInt("connection_state",
                                        BluetoothConnectionService.STATE_CONNECTED);
                                break;

                            case BluetoothConnectionService.STATE_CONNECTING:
                                connectTxt.setText("Connecting...");
                                break;

                            case BluetoothConnectionService.STATE_NONE:

                              tinyDB.putInt("connection_state",
                                      BluetoothConnectionService.STATE_NONE);
                              connectButton.setText("Connect");
                              connectTxt.setText("You're not connectedd");
                                Log.d(CLASS_TAG, connectTxt.getText() + "");
                                btDevice = null;
                                break;
                        }
                        break;

                    case MESSAGE_WRITE:

                        break;
                    case MESSAGE_READ:

                        break;
                    case MESSAGE_DEVICE_NAME:
                        // save the connected device's name
                        connectedDeviceName = msg.getData().getString(DEVICE_NAME);
                        if(connectedDeviceName != null){
                            Toast.makeText(context, "Device: " + connectedDeviceName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                        break;
                    case MESSAGE_TOAST:

                        Log.d(CLASS_TAG + "/" + "handler/toast", "Toast: " + msg.getData().getString(TOAST));
                        Toast.makeText(context, msg.getData().getString(TOAST),
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                }
            }
        };




    @Override
    public void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView(){
        super.onDestroyView();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach(){
        super.onDetach();
        Log.d(CLASS_TAG, "in onDetach() !");
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // Check which request we're responding to

        if (resultCode == getActivity().RESULT_OK && DevicesList.EXTRA_DEVICE_ADDRESS != null) {
            btDevice = btAdapter.getRemoteDevice(data.getExtras().getString(DevicesList.EXTRA_DEVICE_ADDRESS));
            connectedDeviceAddress = data.getExtras().getString(DevicesList.EXTRA_DEVICE_ADDRESS);
            if(connectedDeviceAddress != null){
                btService.connect(btDevice);
            }
            Log.d(CLASS_TAG, "OnActivityResult: " + data.getExtras().getString(DevicesList.EXTRA_DEVICE_ADDRESS));
        } else if (resultCode == -1){
            Log.d(CLASS_TAG, "Bluetooth probably enabled");
        }
    }

    /**
     * Private method for checking if the bluetooth is on or off
     *
     * */
    private void checkBluetoothState() {
        if(btAdapter == null){
            new AlertBox("Fatal error", "Bluetooth not supported. Aborting ", context);
        }else{
            if(btAdapter.isEnabled() != true){
                Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(btAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
                startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
            }
        }
    }


    /**
     * Class for managing onClickListener for connection button
     */
    class ConnectionClickListener implements View.OnClickListener{



        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            switch(tinyDB.getInt("connection_state")){
                case BluetoothConnectionService.STATE_NONE:
                    if(btDevice == null){
                        Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), DevicesList.class);
                        startActivityForResult(i, 1);
                    }
                     break;

                case BluetoothConnectionService.STATE_CONNECTED:
                    if(btService != null){
                        btService.stop();
                        btDevice = null;
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

## HomeFragment xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top">


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_linlay1"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        >


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Status: "
            android:id="@+id/textView" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/main_connect_txt" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Connect"
            android:id="@+id/main_connect_button"
            style="@style/ButtonCheapRoomDuino"/>


    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Next Scenery: "
            android:id="@+id/textView" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="None!"
            android:id="@+id/main_scenery_txt" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Add Scenery"
            android:id="@+id/main_scenery_button"
            style="@style/ButtonCheapRoomDuino"/>
    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Anyone? It really bothers me

Answer (score 0):

I accomplished it. I have my app working like this:

After firing my app, I have MainActivity with HomeFragment created. In HomeFragment I have Button and TextView for connecting / showing state of BluetoothConnection.

In HomeFragment I implemented Handler for receiving information from BluetoothService. After receiving message I wanted to update TextView and Button text. I created public interface in HomeFragment with method that is getting String arguments for TextView and Button. In onAttach(Activity a) I created mCallback object for talking to activity.

Next step is implementing this Interface in MainActivity. From this Activity I am updating TextView and Button. Everything looks like this:

### HomeFragment.java

```
public interface ViewInterface{
    public void onViewUpdate(String buttonTxt, String txtTxt);
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity a){
    super.onAttach(a);
    try{
        mCallback = (ViewInterface)a;
    }catch (ClassCastException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            switch (msg.what) {

                case MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGE:

                    if(true) Log.i(CLASS_TAG, "MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGE: " + msg.arg1);
                    switch (msg.arg1) {
                        case BluetoothConnectionService.STATE_CONNECTED:

                            threadTextString = "Connected to: " + connectedDeviceName;
                            threadBtnString = "Disconnect";
                            mCallback.onViewUpdate(threadBtnString, threadTextString);
                            break;
                        case BluetoothConnectionService.STATE_CONNECTING:
                           threadTextString = "Connecting...";
                            mCallback.onViewUpdate(threadBtnString, threadTextString);
                            break;
                         case BluetoothConnectionService.STATE_NONE:

                            threadBtnString = "Connect";
                            threadTextString = "You're not connectedd";
                            mCallback.onViewUpdate(threadBtnString, threadTextString);
                            break;
}

private void updateBtn(Button btn, String data){
    btn.setText(data);
    Log.d(CLASS_TAG + "/" + "updateBtn", "Data: " + data);
}

private void updateTxt(TextView txt, String data){
    txt.setText(data);
    Log.d(CLASS_TAG + "/" + "updateTxt", "Data: " + data);

}

public void update(String buttonTxt, String txtTxt){
    this.updateTxt(connectTxt, txtTxt);
    this.updateBtn(connectButton, buttonTxt);
}
```

### MainActivity.java

```
@Override
public void onViewUpdate(String buttonTxt, String txtTxt) {
    HomeFragment homeFragment = (HomeFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.frame_container);
    if(homeFragment != null){
    homeFragment.update(buttonTxt, txtTxt);
    }
}
```